# How to while loops work in Scala?

Tags: scala

Would you please explain this code step by step, as I don't understand why there is a inner = 1 in the while loop. A general overview of this program and how it works would be deeply appreciated as I am currently learning loops in Scala!

```
import scala.io.StdIn._

object loops4 {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        var outer = 1;
        var inner = 1;
        print("How many units for the base of the triangle? ");
        var base: Int = readInt();
        while (outer <= base) {
            inner = 1
            while (inner <= outer) {
                print ('*');
                inner += 1;
            }
            println("\n");
            outer += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Asking people to explain the entirety of some code is way too broad. You'll need to narrow this down. And what specifically about the `inner` assignment do you need help understanding? Have you watched the program run in a debugger? Do you understand the general algorithm here?

Comment: *"why there is a inner = 1 in the while loop"* - Well, what happens when you remove that statement and debug the code?  Does it behave differently?  That difference in behavior is likely why that line of code is there.

Answer (score 2):

Don't "learn loops in scala", it's a waste of time. Learn scala.
This does the same thing (except for redundant empty lines between stars) as your snippet, except, I bet you don't have to ask people on internet how it works :)

```
 (1 to base).foreach { n => println("*" * n) }
```

Comment: Learning loops is part of my course at the moment and i also will be tested on it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to debug the code as Carcigenicate suggested. Inner is set to 1 in the outer loop because it's changed to match the outer loop on the previous iteration of the outer loop. Debug and observe inner at the end of the outer loop. As far as what this code is doing, it's constructing a triangle in standard output and the outer loop is counting lines, and the inner loop is constructing the lines with '*' symbols. As Dima said there are more idiomatic ways to do this in Scala.